# Reshape dataset from long to wide (or a different approach to enrich main data set with information)

Tags: python, dataframe

coming from STATA, I have difficulties reshaping my data or I am mistaken on how to deal with the problem in python / a ML problem.

I have multiple data sets, which I will describe here briefly:

Main data set, **ID is unique**, contains information per ID, e.g. a name, an address, sex, ...

```
     +-------------------------------------------+
     |    ID    abc    xyz        ...     ...    |
     |-------------------------------------------|
  1. |    10    5      some       ...     ...    |
  2. |    20    12     strings    ...     ...    |
  3. |    30    3      random     ...     ...    |
  4. |    40    120    info       ...     ...    |
     +-------------------------------------------+
```

Multiple additional data sets, **ID is not unique**, contains information on single features, e.g. colours of t-shirts owned, credit card vendors used ... but there is a **limited number of distinct values** for each additional information (there are only 5 different credit card vendors or only 10 different colours to choose from)

```
     +-----------------+
     |    ID    abc    |
     |-----------------|
  1. |    10    green  |
  2. |    10    red    |
  3. |    10    yellow |
  4. |    20    green  |
  5. |    20    blue   |
  6. |    30    yellow |
     +-----------------+
```

I would like to enrich the main data set with the information from the additional data sets. The only viable solution I have in my mind is reshaping the additional information from long to wide, resulting in a unique ID but additional columns, e.g. ['colour_red', 'colour_greed', ...] and then joining on the main data set.

```
     +----------------------------------------+
     |    ID    green   red   yellow   blue   |
     |----------------------------------------|
  1. |    10    green  red    yellow   NaN    |
  2. |    20    green  NaN    NaN      blue   |
  3. |    30    NaN    NaN    yellow   NaN    |
     +----------------------------------------+

     +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     |    ID    abc    xyz        ...     ...    green   red   yellow   blue  |
     |------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |    10    5      some       ...     ...    green  red    yellow   NaN   |
  2. |    20    12     strings    ...     ...    green  NaN    NaN      blue  |
  3. |    30    3      random     ...     ...    NaN    NaN    yellow   NaN   |
  4. |    40    120    info       ...     ...    NaN    NaN    NaN      NaN   |
     +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I have tried using .pivot but always end up with muiltiindex data frames that were not possible to join with the main data frame as I could not get rid of the index level or did some errors on the course.

Thise raises two questions for me:

1. How to manipulate the data in the way I presented with python (pandas or whatever suits)
2. Am I going the right way? Or would you propose a different way to tackle the problem?

I hope I did stick to the community rules. Thanks upfront for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my take on this question.

My solution is based entirely on your proposed technique. There's maybe a better, more elegant, way to do this.

I used the same datasets you presented in a `pandas.DataFrame` format.
Here is the "main dataset" called `df1`

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[10, 5, "some"], 
                [20, 12, "strings"], 
                [30, 3, "random"], 
                [40, 120, "info"]], 
               columns=["ID", "abc", "xyz"])
```

and here is the "additional dataset" called here `df2`

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[10, "green"],
                    [10, "red"],
                    [10, "yellow"],
                    [20, "green"],
                    [20, "blue"],
                    [20, "yellow"]],
                  columns = ["ID", "abc"])
```

### Part 1: reshape the additional information dataset:

We first want to reshape `df2` as to have as columns the colors ("blue", "green", "red" and "yellow") and each row corresponding to one id.

To do this, I have used the "one-hot-encoding" technique. [read-more here](https://www.kaggle.com/dansbecker/using-categorical-data-with-one-hot-encoding). This is standard and I personally prefer this format as we do not have NaN values and we do not repeat unnecessarily the column names in the column values.

First, we get the one-hot encoded dataframe by using `get_dummies`:

```
df2 = pd.get_dummies(df2, prefix="", prefix_sep="")
```

which looks like:

```
    ID  blue    green   red     yellow
0   10     0        1     0          0
1   10     0        0     1          0
2   10     0        0     0          1
3   20     0        1     0          0
4   20     1        0     0          0
5   20     0        0     0          1
```

Then, we want to group the dataframe on the "ID" column so that one row corresponds to one ID. We can do that using the `groupby` method and combining rows using the `sum` function.

```
df2 = df2.groupby("ID").sum().reset_index()
```

Finally, `df2` (the additional dataset) looks like:

```
    ID  blue    green   red     yellow
0   10     0        1     1          1
1   20     1        1     0          1
```

### Part 2: Join the two dataframes.

```
df3 = pd.merge(left=df1, right=df2, how='left', on="ID", sort=False)
# replace NaN values in the one-hot-encoded vectors with zeros. 
new_columns = ["blue", "green", "red", "yellow"] # One-hot- encoded columns
df3[new_columns] = df3[new_columns].fillna(0).astype(int) # fill na
```

Finally, the `df3` dataframe looks like:

```
    ID  abc     xyz     blue    green   red     yellow
0   10    5     some       0        1     1          1
1   20   12     strings    1        1     0          1
2   30    3     random     0        0     0          0
3   40  120     info       0        0     0          0
```